# Angular: Dependency in Router Reuse Strategy

Tags: angular

I am using router reuse strategy to save the previous routes in my Angular 6 based application. I have injected my breadcrumb service in that custom route reuse strategy.
When store method is called to check whether previous route is saved or not, I am calling a method of breadcrumb service which method basically emits an event.
But the component which is subscribing that emit event is not called, why?

My question: Can we emit the event when restoring the previous routes, if yes, then how?

**routereuseservice.ts**

```
// Router Class

export class RouteReuseService implements RouteReuseStrategy {

  private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  constructor(private breadService:BreadCrumbService) {
  }

  //Store method which stores the route

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void 
 {
    this.handlers[route.url.join("/") || route.parent.url.join("/")] = handle;
    if(handle == null) 
    {
       this.initbreadcrumb(route);
    }
  }

 //method which is used to emit event

  initbreadcrumb(route) {
   this.breadService.event(data);
  }

}
```

**breadService.ts**

```
// Bread Crumb Service

export class BreadCrumbService {

   eventEmit = new EventEmitter();
   event(response) {
     //event emitter
      this.eventEmit.emit(response);
   }

   getEmitter()
   {
      return this.eventEmit;
   }
}
```

**UserComponent.ts**

```
//My Component
export class UserComponent {

    ngOnInit() 
   { 
       //subscribing the emitted event
        this.subscription = this.breadService.getEmitter().subscribe((item) => {
             if(item!=undefined)
             this.onEventHandler(item);
          });
    }
 }
```

The event being emitted is not being subscribed. Why?

Comment: Hi. Please fix the formatting of your code, its really hard to read this way.

Comment: Are you registering your `RouteReuseService` in the module? Can you be sure your custom strategy is being called?

Comment: Yes, I am sure my RouteReuseService is added and being called whenever i route back to the previous route